# Angular 5 on input change

Tags: angular, forms

I have to create a form to edit a balance sheet. The model behind it is an object made of 3 levels (at least) of nested objects. e.g.:

```
financialData: {
  assets: {
    total: 0,
    currentAssests: {total: 0, detail: 0, otherDetail: 0, ...},
    nonCurrentAssets: {total: 0, detail: 0, otherDetail: 0, ...},
    ...
  },
  liabilities: {...}
}
```

How can I calculate the different total fields when any input changes? All inputs are bound to a model property. I tried to use the `(ngModelChange)="computeTotals()"` directive, but it is called before the model is actually changed, making the calculation false. 
I tried `OnChanges`, but the model itself is not changed, only nested properties.

The closest thing I got working is using `DoCheck`, but it gets called a lot. And if I want to filter using `this.differ = differs.find({}).create()`, I need to create a differ for all nested objects.

What is the most simple way to make sure that I calculate each total when one input is changed?

My form is reasonably large, about 30 fields and 10 total fields. I don't really want to have a dedicated method for each input, and I want to be able to maintain the form easily.

Comment: Do you know reactive forms ? if so, do you know `valueChanges` ?

Comment: I am using template-driven form, because it easier for me to manipulate an existing model. I think that a reactive form will make the maintenance of the form much more complicated. Now I might be wrong, and if so would love to know why.

Comment: I can't answer to that question over hte little knowledge I have over your project. But I can definitely tell you that in a `FormControl` (Angular class related to reactive forms), you have `FormControl.prototype.valueChanges`, which spies on the changes made on an input, which is what you want. Otherwise, you can simply bind to the `(input)` event, but since I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, I can't guarantee you it will work.

Comment: That would mean creating programmatically, creating a list of form controls in the component. Isn't that a lot of work for 30 fields? It may be more powerful to achieve some validation and computation tasks, but wouldn't maintainability be exponentially increasing?

Comment: Not at all, you can simply do `this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group(this.financialData);`, and your form is created. After that, you will simply have to make your template, but either way you have to do that.

Comment: I tried this, and it seems that it stops after only one nested element. I ended up creating a form manually. It's very verbose, but at least I can handle sub-totals per section.

Comment: That's because you have to declare new groups for every object. This is very well described in their guide about [dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form). As a side note, what I usually do is an `utils` function that returns a nested formGroup for every nested object in the variable.

Comment: I was reading the angular doc while proceeding with this form, I could also point to that [useful tutorial](https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4) which helped me creating the form. In the end creating the the form manually may be work but it makes the code readable and searchable. As a bonus question, is there a way to force some _FormControls_ to stay disabled although the parent _FormGroup_ is enabled? some of my totals need to be read-only.

Comment: `new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})`

Comment: of course, but in case I do `formGroup.enable()`, the enclosed _FormControl_ will change state. So far I do this, but it seems a bit buggy: `formGroup.get('assetsTotal').valueChanges.subscribe(() => formGroup.get('assetsTotal').disable({ emitEvent: false }))`. It seems the browser is not notified that the field is disabled.

Comment: Well, probably because you're telling it to not emit an event ?

Comment: if emitting an event -> infinite loop. good is good enough. I'll leave it to rest and get back when needed. Thanks for the support

Comment: Well, you should then correct the infinite loop, that's an issue on your end. And no problem, good luck with your project !